# Which is good practice ? Exposing primary key in db or finding the user with some other unique key?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Here is my scenerio. Am creating an backend with node, express and sequelize for React native mobile app. Lets assume that we have two tables - one is User and another is Wallet ( both are in 1to1 association ).

Here is my question, when i need to find a associations with Wallet table, i need to send an userId from user table ( as its the foreign key ), check this code

```
const {userID} = req.params;
return db.B.findOne({
        where: { userId },
        include: {
          model: db.User,
          attributes: ['name', 'email'],
        },
      })
```

So whats the good practice ? sending userId via params and then passing directly to the findOne query or else sending some unique userdetails like "email".

So that, i can find the user with email and then user that ID to do the second query ?

Which is good practice ?

As the second one takes two query to find the user and use that userId to find the wallet associated ?

Answer (score 0):

This is really an opinion-based question as there could be scenarios where you might want to use the email, but:

Just use the unique, permanent, non-changing identifier (user ID) instead of an email.

Comment: You mean, instead of finding the user with email and the using the founded users userId, i should be directly using / passing userID ?